# Argument Null Exception error using dictionary store prefab and instantiate it in game scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game has player ships. User selected ship is instantiated in game scene on launchpad, I am using dictionary to store selected ship by taking ship no from save file(savemanage.instance.state.activeship) and then using switch statement to pass name of ship prefab in SpawnShip function. but it gives me error

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].FindEntry (TKey key) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0) System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].ContainsKey (TKey
> key) (at :0) PlayerSpawn.SpawnShip
> (System.String name) (at Assets/Script/PlayerSpawn.cs:24)
> PlayerSpawn.Start () (at Assets/Script/PlayerSpawn.cs:46)

Here is the script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject launchPad;
    private string OrangeShip;
    string BlueShip;
    string RedShip;
    string YellowShip;
    private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);

    private Dictionary<string, GameObject> PlayerShip = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();

    public void SpawnShip(string name)
    {
        if (launchPad == null)
        {
            launchPad = GameObject.Find("Launch Pad");
        }

        if (!PlayerShip.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            var  go = Resources.Load<GameObject>("PlayerShips/" + name);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("PlayerShips/" + name);

            if (go == null)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("tried to instatiate playership" + name + ".but it does not exist");
                return;
            }
            PlayerShip.Add(name, go);
        }
        GameObject.Instantiate(PlayerShip[name]);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        int shipNo = SaveManager.Instance.state.activeShip;

        switch(shipNo)
        {
            case 0:
                SpawnShip(OrangeShip);

                break;
            case 1:
                SpawnShip(BlueShip);
                break;
            case 2:
                SpawnShip(RedShip); 
                break;
            case 3:
                SpawnShip(YellowShip); 
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the exception because you have not set any value to the `OrangeShip`, `BlueShip`, `RedShip` and `YellowShip`. Please assign the required value to these

Comment: i didn't get that which value and where i need to assign it? I am new to unity and coding.

Comment: the problem you are facing not related to unity, its basic C# question